# How to show the structure of a pdf document with LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, navigation

How to show the document structure with Latex?. I was doing some article and i would like to know once it was been compiled and saved in a pdf file how to show the sections or the strcuture of the text in order to facilitate the reading?

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}`  ...     `\tableofcontents` should do the job ;)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that what you look for is Table of Contents (ToC), which is included by the command `\tableofcontents`. If you call `\usepackage{hyperref}` as well, the items in the ToC will be clickable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\subsection{Its subsection}

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```